# How to update object using spread operator

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to update object using spread object, but not able to correctly update it. 
This is the result I want in first switch case:

```
{
  code: {
    loading: true
  }
}
```

And in second switch case, this is what I want:

```
{
  code : {
    loading: false,
    data: {
      some data here
    }
  }
}
```

```
const downloadData = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOADING: {
            const {code, loading} = action.payload
            return {
                ...state,
                [code]: {
                    ...[code], loading
                }
            }
        }

        case LOADED: {
            const {code, loading, data} = action.payload
            return {
                ...state,
                [code] : {
                    loading, data, ...[code]
                }
            }
        }

        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your initial state object look like?

Comment: It's just empty object

Comment: NO, NO, NO. State object is only empty if it's not defined. Once you defined it should look like the first or second snippet (via LOADING or LOADED)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have initial state

```
const initialState = {
  code: {
    loading: false,
    data: {}
  }
};
```

For the first case try:

```
{
  ...state,
  code: {
    ...state.code,
    loading: true
  }
}
```

For second case:

```
{
  ...state,
      code: {
        ...state.code,
        loading: false,
        data: {
              some data here
              }
      }    
}
```

Comment: It works can you please check here https://repl.it/repls/AutomaticAliveKeychanger

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar Used your solution, and it's working exactly like I needed. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I think your second case should be:

```js
case LOADED: {
    const {code, loading, data} = action.payload
    return {
        ...state,
        code : {
            ...code,
            loading:false,
            data: {some data here}
        }
    }
}
```

Because the `loading` and `data` will overwrite the `...[code]`

Comment: Earlier I was trying this same thing, but not working